# Solver - Excel Portfolio Selection | Problem with Clacluation & Restrictions, Efficient Frontier

Tags: excel, math, solver, portfolio

attached you can find my Excel Portfolio, feel free to use it if you have any usage for it.

My problem:

on sheet "Portfolio" i wanted to illustrate the efficient frontier but for that i have to make some calculations with the solver. Within Data -> Solver the restrictions should still be included so you are able to understand what has to be solved.

Regarding a Minimium Variance Portfolio i use the target "Variance" and "Minimize" this to what is at minimum possible regarding the range of selected shares. The Minimum Variance in my portfolio is SSYS with 7,5% of Standard Deviation. So when i use next to the target the following restrictions

Cells of Change: Weights

```
Weights of Selection = 1
Weights of Selection >= 0
Target Return = Return of SSYS
```

then i expect by logic that 100% of Weight is asssigned to SSYS

It worked...once and then it seems by reason i do not understand, it didnt work anymore.

The result is always that solver could not find any possibilities under the restrictions (what is not possible).

Do you have an idea?

[https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hdzmwr2ypkozw0vwj7mlu/Base-Portfolio_0321.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=5qy2k6xryqcb2lszhetp3f0bv#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wuYl.jpg)

**EDIT 23.04.2021**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit 02.05.21**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @sven I don't want to download an excel spreadsheet with macros from your dropbox. Is there anyway you can show screenshots of the solver you have set up in the question?

Comment: @cabbagetreecustard i see :) ...i added pictures within my question, i hope it helps. You can see for example that once the solver was working because on the graph the Minimum Variance Portfolio is included. I appreciate your help

Comment: We need to see your cell formulas. Can you a `ctrl` + ` ctrl+tilde? This will convert the view from result to formula.

Comment: @JWeezy thanks for helping. I put attached the snippets within my answer. FIrst prcture is the already know overview = final sheet. Second one shows the VarCov Matrix divided in 2 Parts (1.Part for the log. diff. returns, 2.Part divided by C2 = N = 505 returns). The second part is the soruce for the values F535:G549 which determins the variance for each asset / Still the Problem: The solver can not create a scenario by the restrictions